# How can I control the pulling power of a DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor

I have a project where a DC motor needs to pull on a yarn and keep it a constant tension. The tension also needs to be adjustable.

I have tried to google this but it seems like I am not asking the right questions...

Would it be as simple as reading the motor current and adjusting the voltage to reduce the current or do I have it totally wrong?

Also would it be bad for a dc motor to be energized all the time and not moving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you want a motor control that allows you to set the current to the motor.  Most controllers have this ability, sometimes by directly accepting a torque reference, or indirectly by controlling the current limits.

It is probably best to control the current limit, and leave the controller in speed mode... with this approach, the motor will not run away (overspeed) on a yarn break, but most low end DC Drives do not have the ability to control the current limit via a voltage signal.  You would have to find one that does.  Most digital DC drives allow this type of operation.

To go even further, it wouldn't be a bad idea to mount a load cell idler roll in order to directly measure the tension on your web.  Then you can use either an external PID controller or one internal to a digital drive to actually control tension if the motor is used as a winder.  If it is just a pull roll, a constant torque (current limit) should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Typically in a motor current is proportional to torque, so you need to have a motor controller that can deliver a controlled current.

Whether or not it is bad to have the motor engaged and not moving depends on the motor and how much current you are pushing through it while stalled. You could easily push too much power into it and overheat it if you do not control current to a reasonable level based on how much power the motor can dissipate.

Answer (score -1):

I've a very similar application for pulling string to a constant and repeatable tension, I'm considering using a worm motor such as the ones for opening windows and pair with a adjustable current limiter.

I need a precise tension between 20-30 lbs every time it is pulled, would this setup work, or there is a better alternative ?

Comment: This is not an answer. If you have a new question, create one and, if needed, reference the original question.